# Filling a bi-dimensional array in JavaScript using a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

So, I need to fill a bi-dimensional array in JavaScript and I'm doing it the following way:

```
var i = 0, j = 0;
for (i = 0; i < roomWidth / tileWidth; i += 1) {
     roomBuffer[i] = [];
}
for (i = 0; roomWidth / tileWidth; i += 1) {
     for (j = 0; j < roomHeight / tileHeight; j += 1) {
          roomBuffer[i][j] = 1;
     }
}
alert("Hello world");
```

The problem is that it not only doesn't work but any code that comes after it, it's not executed. In this case the `alert("Hello world");`. What am I doing wrong guys?

Comment: If your script stops executing then your browser should log an error in its console. Hopefully that could give you a clue as to what's going on; it's hard for us to know without the full code, for example what is the roomWidth variable?

Comment: where are you declaring roombuffer?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers! I should have checked the javascript console before asking here though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change

```
for (i = 0; roomWidth / tileWidth; i += 1) {
```

to

```
for (i = 0; i < roomWidth / tileWidth; i += 1) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to declare `i` and `j` before the loops. If their existence is solely for the loops, they are better off as local variables. Also, you can combine loops.

Also, what @Yuriy Zubarev said is right. The middle statement in the `for`-loop is a condition that must hold true throughout the loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < roomWidth / tileWidth; i++) {
     roomBuffer[i] = [];
     for (var j = 0; j < roomHeight / tileHeight; j++) {
          roomBuffer[i][j] = 1;
     }
}
alert("Hello world");
```

Comment: You're misunderstanding javascript's scoping rules. i and j will not be discarded after the loops.

Comment: Don't call them local variables :S and it's not good to declare them inside the for loop. The general consensus is manually hoisting variable declarations to the top of the containing function is best.

Comment: @david really?? I'm new to JavaScript but I've been coding in Java for years (ok, so only 3 years) but I was *always* taught that it's best to declare the loop counter inside the loop definition...

Comment: That's because Java is block scoped, javascript is function scoped. If you declare them inside the loop definition you're just lying to yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hrishikeshp19/TgF7S/) fiddle.

change your

```
for (i = 0; roomWidth / tileWidth; i += 1)
```

to

```
for (i = 0; i < roomWidth / tileWidth; i += 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code by using a small helper function

```
// create an array of length len filled with value
fill = function(len, value) {
    for (var a = []; len-- > 0; a.push(value));
    return a;
}
```

Your code:

```
size = roomWidth / tileWidth
roomBuffer = fill(size, fill(size, 1))
```